# Make Adjustments To final_price Render Class On Product Pages Magento2

Tags: product, price, overrides, magento-2.1.2

I am trying to change the render class for the final_price renderer on the product pages in Magento2. I have found the following block inside the vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/layout/catalog_product_prices.xml file:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool" name="render.product.prices">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="default_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\PriceBox</item>
            <item name="default_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/default.phtml</item>
            <item name="default_amount_render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount</item>
            <item name="default_amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
            <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="special_price" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/special_price.phtml</item>
                </item>
                <item name="tier_price" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/tier_prices.phtml</item>
                </item>
                <item name="final_price" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox</item>
                    <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/final_price.phtml</item>
                </item>
                <item name="custom_option_price" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="amount_render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/amount/default.phtml</item>
                </item>
                <item name="configured_price" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\ConfiguredPriceBox</item>
                    <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/price/configured_price.phtml</item>
                </item>
            </item>
            <!--<item name="adjustments" xsi:type="array"></item>-->
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

I have setup a custom module to apply the update. What layout XML would I need to use to update the class without replacing the entire block? Would I make use of the *adjustments* item that is commented out of the above snippet?

Answer (score 0):

try this by adding the current layout in your module 
and replace the above code with this

```
        <arguments>
            <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="final_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Your Class Name</item>
                    </item>
                </item>    
            </argument>
        </arguments>
```

Comment: I tried the above and received the following fatal error: 'Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Price code "final_price" render block not configured'. Is using the adjustment item node not the way to go with this?